# In Google Groups, is it possible to see the content of my posts that are held in moderation?

Tags: google-groups

I stupidly didn't save the content of a well-crafted post anywhere before I submitted it to a Google Group, but it's being held in moderation.

I want to send the question to someone else, but I don't want to take the time to rewrite it (and possibly screw up some of the details).

Can I see the contents of the post before it is published to the group, or is it in moderation limbo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submitted it via email you can find it in your `Sent Mail` label, otherwise you can ask the group moderator to send it back to you.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. Sent mail folder!

Comment: We've all been there.  :-)